# Delphi, olevariants and arrays of strings

Tags: delphi, arrays, delphi-7, ole, variant

i have an ole Object created with (simple verion)

```
obj := CreateOleObject('foo.bar');
obj.OnResult := DoOnResult;

procedure TMyDM.DoOnResult(Res: olevariant);
```

which all works, the res variable has a function *String[] GetAns()*
which im calling like this

```
var
 ans: array of string;
begin
 ans := Res.GetAns;
end;
```

which again works.. except sometimes no array is returned, and then an exception is thrown.

as a temporary solution i have wrapped it in a empty try except block, which i know is *bad*. I have tried  *VarIsArray(Res.GetAns)*  but it still donst work if the result is null

What is the correct way check for the right result?

*ps I have no control over the ole Object*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Christopher try using the [`VarIsNull`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.VarIsNull) function

```
procedure TMyDM.DoOnResult(Res: olevariant);
var
 ans: array of string;
begin
 if not VarIsNull(Res) then 
 if not VarIsNull(Res.GetAns) then
 begin
  ans := Res.GetAns;
  //do your stuff

 end;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks i glanced over that one didn't even think twice about it for some reason. Seems to work as needed :)